# JQuery Ajax Method doesn't submit success data as an Array

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have Jquery Ajax function to get data from MVC controller. Ajax method call perfectly but not in the correct area. Controller method hit after the success method in Ajax call. 
I'm returning Array from controller to ajax method. But it is not working. when I'm set the alert in success it will popup. i cant assign array value to define variables.
Pls help me to sort out this.

Jquery Ajax Method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            var austDay = new Date();
            var currDay = new Date();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Service/Utility/GetDownDate',
                success: function (countDownDetail) {
                    if (countDownDetail.Result.length > 0) {
                        austDay = countDownDetail.Result[0];
                        currDay = countDownDetail.Result[1];
                    }
                }
            });

            austDay = new Date(austDay, 1 - 1, 26);



            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: austDay });
            $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
        });
</script>
```

This is MVC Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult GetDownDate()
    {
        string dtime = db.Maintanance.FirstOrDefault().Time;
        string[] time = dtime.Split(':');

        //int hours = db.Maintanance.FirstOrDefault().date.Hour+;
        DateTime downDate = db.Maintanance.FirstOrDefault().date;
        int minutes = db.Maintanance.FirstOrDefault().duration + Convert.ToInt32(time[1]);

        DateTime newDate = new DateTime(downDate.Year, downDate.Month, downDate.Day, Convert.ToInt32(time[0]), minutes, 0);
        DateTime currentDate = System.DateTime.Now;

        DateTime[] dateTimes = new DateTime[]
        {
            newDate,currentDate
        };

        return Json(new
        {
            Value = dateTimes

        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            );
    }
```

Thank You,,

Comment: where you are passing array values in code ? it seems u passing date object

Comment: Here data not bind in to "success: function (countDownDetail)" countDownDetail, That is the issue i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are returing something to Ajax sucess, you need to use rertun JSON not return view  like below code

```
 public ActionResult GetDownDate()

    {
    .............

    DateTime downDate = db.Maintanance.FirstOrDefault().date;
                int minutes = db.Maintanance.FirstOrDefault().duration + Convert.ToInt32(time[1]);

                DateTime newDate = new DateTime(downDate.Year, downDate.Month, downDate.Day, Convert.ToInt32(time[0]), minutes, 0);
    return Json(new { date = newDate }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

in success function like

```
success: function (data) {
//data will contain date objects
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get hold of the HTTP response object and use the write method.

response.getWriter().write(View(newDate));

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Return string instead of array using function like implode() with some seperator and split the result using split function in javascript.

```
 success: function (countDownDetail) {
    var countDownResult=countDownDetail.split(seperator);
    if ( countDownResult.length > 0) {
        austDay =  countDownResult[0];
        currDay =  countDownResult[1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: it seems OP is not returning array in controller.